# Transcript of discussion between Elon Musk and Israeli PM Benyamin Netanyahu on 18 Sep 2023?

Tags: israel, reference-request

Is there a publicly available transcript of the discussion that took place between Elon Musk and Israeli PM Benyamin Netanyahu in Los Angeles on 18 September 2023?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Rev has published a transcript of the event [here](https://www.rev.com/blog/transcripts/elon-musk-and-benjamin-netanyahu-discuss-ai-anti-semitism-and-charging-fees-for-x-transcript). There's then a break, and the panel adding Max Tegmark and Greg Brockman is transcribed [here](https://www.rev.com/blog/transcripts/ai-safety-panel-with-elon-musk-max-tegmark-greg-brockman-and-benjamin-netanyahu-transcript). Rev is pretty good for transcribing high-profile events; I usually use them for scanning through presidential debates.

For future reference, a great way to find these transcripts is to take a verbatim quote from the event, and put that into Google in quotation marks along with the word transcript - for example [like so](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22What%20you%E2%80%99re%20saying%20is%20there%20are%20barriers%20to%20entry,%20that%20will%20be%20difficult%20to%20overcome.%22%20%22transcript%22).

Comment: Many thanks for this quick and helpful reply.